# Going Back and forth between Userforms

Tags: vba, userform

Hello everyone on my userfrom I have a previous and a next button
the previous button on userform 1 contains a next button which the code looks something like this

```
userform1.hide
userform2.show
```

on userform 2 I have a previous button that looks like this

```
userform2.hide
userform1.show
```

but when I go back to userform1 and foreward to userform 2 I get an error message that states this.

run-time error '400':

Form already displayed; can't show modally.

is there anyway I can fix this or create an if statement to help I am lost right now. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide first, then show.

```
userform1.Hide
userform2.Show
```

Also, within the form, you could say ME:

```
Me.Hide
UserForm2.Show
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like "Multipage" in the toolbox would also be handful here !